# How to send message to particular Client Channel in Netty from netty server handler

Tags: client, netty

Right now i am confusing to get client channel without iterating channels  group so how i can achieve that **things**.

Answer (score 1):

You can store each `Channel` in a `HashMap<String, ChannelHandlerContext>` where key can be `Channel.id().asLongText()`.